# How to get Pull Status/Up-To-Date status from Remote Repository?

Tags: c#, .net, git, libgit2sharp

I'm using the Library "libgit2sharp" to integrate into my project where I want to check if my local repository is up-to-date with the remote repository, pull/commit wise.

I want to know this, so if it's not up to date, I then do a "Pull" and do some other stuff in my program.

And If it IS up-to-date, I need to know that somehow.

What can you do in the library to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to perform a git fetch, as described in [libgit2sharp
 git-fetch](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-fetch).

Check what has been created by the fetch like [`TestHelpers/ExpectedFetchState.cs`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/3615df921ded6e58b08bc438645d9291804f5db1/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/TestHelpers/ExpectedFetchState.cs) does: it nothing has been added (no branch/tags/commit), then your repo is up-to-date.

Comment: How would you check what's being created in a repository.Network.Fetch() ? It doesn't seem to return anything, and the "RepositoryOperationCompleted" delegate that can be assigned, doesn't have much valuable information upon completion of the fetch.

Could you come with a code example?

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen See its usage in https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/5d0cb35b89ada4b347bc4b763895ee8b263591c2/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/FetchFixture.cs: it records the state of the repo *before* the fetch, and helps comparing with the state of the repo *after* the Fetch.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never been great at reading these kinds of Tests and convert them into the right code. Sure you can't just help me out with a code example specific for my issue? :)

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen Sorry, this was meant as a stating point to illustrate how libgit2sharp itself tests the result of a git fetch (which, as you noted, returns nothing by default) In your case, you need an helper class which will record the current state (list branches and their HEAD, and tags), then you perform the fetch as you already know how, and then that ame helper class can list again branches, HEADS and tags, and see if there was any difference.

Comment: Interesting. I'm surprised this isn't an actual functionality in the library itself. Obviously, I can't be the first one to think about this :) But I'll see if I can integrate it. Thank you Vonc :)

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen Sure: if you do integrate it, you can post an answer here.